# Cross Prod Rolling Values

Tags: r, rollup, cross-product, slam

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate rolling sum values based on a vector of data.Below is a sample dataframe and the answer I am trying to compute, but can't figure out the proper solution. Essentially, i'm trying to multiply each x column value by the y vector and sum based on the period.

```
period= c(1,2,3)
x=c(1,1,1)
y= c(2,3,4)

df=data.frame(period,x,y)

This is how I solved the answer.

2+0+0
3+2+0
4+3+2
0+4+3
0+0+4

answer= c(2,5,9,7,4)
```

I've looked at the slam package as well as the crossprod function to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what role does `period` play in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is to calculate a rolling sum of 3 values such that there are implicitly 0s added to ensure that the output has 5 elements even though the input has 3 then try these:

**1) rollapply** Multiply `x` and `y` and insert 0's depending on whether right, center or left alignment is used and depending on whether `partial=` is used.  `align="center"` is the default of `rollapply` and `align = "right"` is the default of `rollapplyr`.

```
library(zoo)

rollapply(c(0, x*y, 0), 3, sum, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4

rollapplyr(c(x*y, 0, 0), 3, sum, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4

rollapplyr(c(0, 0, x*y), 3, sum, align = "left", partial = TRUE)
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4

rollapply(c(0, 0, x*y, 0, 0), 3, sum)
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4

rollsum(c(0, 0, x*y, 0, 0), 3) #  this solution has the lowest character count
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4
```

**2) Base R** A base solution can be written using `embed`:

```
rowSums(embed(c(0, 0, x*y, 0, 0), 3))
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4
```

**2a)** or take the cumulative sum and subtract the cumulative sum 3 back:

```
cumsum(c(x*y,0,0)) - cumsum(c(0, 0, 0, (x*y)[-3]))
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4
```

**2b)** If the idea is that a circular calculation is to be done then:

```
c(filter(c(0, x*y, 0), c(1,1,1), circular = TRUE))
## [1] 2 5 9 7 4
```

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
c(cumsum(df$y), rev(cumsum(rev(df$y)))[-1])
# [1] 2 5 9 7 4
```

`cumsum(df$y)` gives a cumulative sum starting from one end, then `rev(cumsum(rev(df$y))` gives starting from the other one, and we have `[-1]` as full sums coincide:

```
cumsum(df$y)
# [1] 2 5 9
rev(cumsum(rev(df$y)))
# [1] 9 7 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to do a similar calculation by group, the code below should work.

```
df_nest<-df%>% group_by(variable)%>%nest()

df_nest%>%
  mutate(NewColumn = map(data, ~rollapplyr(c(.$x*.$y, 0, 0), 3, sum, partial = TRUE)))%>%
  unnest()
```